# Filter in Interactive Grid with operator 'contains' with values from LOV

Tags: filter, oracle-apex, lov

I'm working with Oracle APEX version 23.1

I have an interactive grid including column `colA` with values `val1:val2` or `val` or `val2:var2`,...
I want to perform filtering on this column (for example: all rows that have `colA` `contains` value `val1`).

In setup of Column Filter, I used a LOV containing values `val1`, `val2`, `val3` to display list of interesting values.

When running application, I perform filtering by directly clicking on header of column `colA` and select value `val1` from dropdown list. However, this produces different behavior than I expected. The filtering is done with operator `Equals` instead of `Contains`, hence only 1 row with exact value `val1` is returned, while I want 2 rows with either `val1` or `val1:val2`.

In Column Filter, I turned off exact match, starts with, case insensitive, regular expression. But it still does not work.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to filter with wildcards (%) as described here:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-C3921F3A-52B3-473D-A93F-D198DED21BA9

So for your example, simply type in the column filter `%val1%` or `val1%`. Clicking an entry in the dropdown, will indeed automatically use `Equals`

[image]